# Couldn't find with 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i use method 'destroy' show me an error

```
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000045e14c0>
```

method destroy

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end
```

view

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(@posts),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

sorry for my bad English

Comment: How is `@posts` created?

Comment: http://pastie.org/9715403

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing a particular post to the link_to method?

Comment: @vveare138 Its perfectly acceptable and preferable to put that information in the question (you can edit your own post to add information). However, that doesn't show me where `@posts` is created. What pdoherty926 said is probably correct, however we need more information to be sure.

Comment: sorry, now update a post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `@posts` variable defined as a ActiveRecord::Relation (some kind of models array, defined with `@posts = Post.all` or anything like that). To fix your issue, if you have link_to call inside index url, most probably you are doing something like:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  # link_to call somewhere here
<% end %>
```

Then you have to change your link_to call to

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Notice we use variable defined in .each do |var| block, here it's `post`